# What's going on with Stack Overflow T-Shirts?

Tags: discussion, t-shirt

Secret organizations have let us know that Jeff has a pile of SO t-shirts hidden somewhere under his bed... What's going to happen to them?

[image: Boxes]

<sub>freehand circles are intentionally omitted</sub>

Comment: WTF? Blatantly Offensive?

Comment: I like the black one personally.

Comment: @Troggy: It's hard to decide but I think black one is more "wearable". The SO logo is not designed for a dark background though.

Comment: @Fearless: Yah, that is good way to put it.  I would be happy to just to be able to get one. ;)

Comment: Omitting freehand circles intentionally is an offense! You should be glad that I do not flag it.

Comment: @Kyle, any chance you can upload that 2nd image again? (`tinypic.info` has gone bad.)

Comment: @Arjan Unfortunately, I don't have it. I think I found it in a tweet from one of the staff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He will send them out free, they'll take over our bodies and we'll become StackOverflow automatons.

Oh wait, **I'm already there**.

Answer (score 5):

A white L is underway to me! Cheer!

**Update:** got it!!

[image: Crappy campic, my wife took our Canon to the Netherlands and she's only after 3 weeks back]

### Many thanks, SO crew!! :)

Comment: How did you order one?

Comment: @Kyle: I got an email this morning that said something about the first three pages of users -- but I didn't have time to read it closely, so that's all the information I have.

Comment: @Kyle - There is no way to order them yet.  The first three pages of users on SO (25.5k rep and greater as of right now) got an email this morning with the offer of a free t-shirt as thanks for their contribution to SO.

Comment: @mmyers @Pollyanna Thanks. I guess it'll be a while before he gets to page 9 though. Starting to really feel that -4.8k rep drop.

Comment: @Pollyana: The first page users got their emails *long* ago. I haven't received mine yet though.

Answer (score 1):

I already got mine...Maybe Jeff doesn't like you as much as he likes me.

Comment: Seriously? I'd love one of these.

Comment: Not seriously...

Answer (score 1):

- Date, a few days to go before start of April. Check
- Country, non US of A. Check
- Check size, "svelte yet manly". Check

OK, I'm in...

Many thanks... or should I say *Vielen Dank*

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. I just ordered the black one (XL), which was a no-brainer in my opinion. Formal enough for work, informal enough for a seedy night club. I can't wait to gloat at the office.

Answer (score 0):

Great stuff, cheers! White XL on its way.

Comment: How did you order one?

Comment: @Kyle got mail today with a link to a Google spreadsheet. Seemed to be addressed to users on the first 3 pages on SO.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I did notice that the 3 new replies to this thread all had ~30k SO rep

Comment: @Kyle let me know if you need the link to sneak your name in :) But I'm sure you're getting yours soon, being a moderator on Meta.

Comment: Damn, nowhere near the first three pages (p8 currently)

Comment: @Pekka That's what I would have thought, but I never got the email. I actually did get the link from Bill back in February and I filled it out, but since I don't have a shirt, I'm assuming that I'm not elegible.

Comment: @Kyle *"I moderate the hellh^H^H^H^H^H site that is Meta, and all I got is .... not even a T-Shirt?"* Naah, that can't be. That would be a scandal. Seriously now. Jeff (or somebody else from the team) to the rescue! This man deserves a T-Shirt more than most of us.

Comment: Although I now, three months later, must say that I have maybe been taken too literally here: I still haven't received my T-Shirt, while others in Germany have!