# Is there a stackoverflow t-shirt, or is it just vaporwear?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What size T-Shirt would you want?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35480/what-size-t-shirt-would-you-want)
>   [What’s going on with Stack Overflow T-Shirts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38018/whats-going-on-with-stack-overflow-t-shirts)

Is it vaporwear or does such a thing exist?

Can I buy one?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=t-shirt&sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: Vote to get your size: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35480

Comment: All questions must be asked in the form of a question.

Comment: Any question without an appropriate mark will be closed as Not a Question. SO Police. (If this wasn't meta we'd have tasered you by now.)

Comment: What would be an "appropriate mark"?

Comment: @ongle: A freehand circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Next Step: putting up a page that lets you buy them.

Comment: Amazon can do that for you...

Comment: How about allowing users to buy a shirt with reputation?

Comment: @waiwai933, wonderful idea - thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Kyle Cronin, seems like that would place a monetary value on your rep... and a relatively low one at that... a similar idea for a non-physical product (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25179/enable-trading-so-reputation-for-listing-cvs-on-so-careers) didn't go over so well

Comment: @Alex Hm, it does seem that people are against the idea of using rep to 'buy' things, even if they're intrinsically linked to the Stack Overflow ecosystem, as the shirt would be. I understand the reasoning behind the psychological motivations, but I think that seeing as the t-shirt doesn't have any value except to the already active users of Stack Overflow, it's not capable of replacing the intrinsic motivation to participate in the site.

Comment: Can I pay the international postage with my rep?