# Reputation should be the new Chuck E. Cheese tickets!

Tags: feature-request, reputation, waffles, fun

We all loved Chuck E. Cheeses as a kid. Lots of games, a big weird looking mouse, PIZZA, and the coolest part! Tickets == Prizes! Well, since we've grown up we haven't had that kinda enjoyment. I recommend to the stack overflow team that they correct this injustice and give us prizes in exchange for rep. Something like bouncy balls for like 50 rep a piece, a cool plasma light thing for 8000 rep, and of course for Jon Skeet, a decked out >$1000 laptop for 100,000 rep.

Not only would this make stack overflow more fun, but it would help to level the playing field. Jon Skeet gets a laptop and from then on no one can complain that he has more reputation and therefore obtains more reputation..

Your thoughts on the subject? Prize ideas?

Comment: Reputation should be like Bing Rewards credits...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about instead of this we can earn rep by playing skee-ball?

Comment: I love skee-ball. I have 1k tickets to exchange...

Comment: Skee-ball is *okay* , I guess. ..... What I really like to play, is Jon-Skeet-ball.

Comment: @MrLister I find your comment much funnier than my own.

Answer (score 2):

I'm all good.  I still play at Chuck E. Cheese.

Comment: A co-worker at my last job used to work there.  I learned from him that you do _not_ want to play in the ball pit!

Comment: @Joel: There's a story there ... One that I'm both captivated by and horrified of.

Comment: @user - Parents don't always watch their young children while they're playing in the ball pit, and, well, let's just say, sometimes diapers leak.

Comment: @Joel @User: yeah, I have a friend who worked there through high-school and college.  It got cleaned, um, well, 4 times that she saw.

Comment: And kids eat too much pizza and lose their lunch...

Comment: **EWWWWWWWWW.**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that then rep translates into money. And then there are all sorts of scams and politics involved because it involves money.

Comment: yea.. thats why we also make it to where your reputation *can* go below 1 and then they have to pay SO/give SO prizes. I'm sure the team would like prizes too. They shouldn't be left out.

Comment: Whereas clearly there are absolutely *no* scams/politics involved when rep is just a number.  No sir, none whatsoever.  *(Must...hit...20k....then...kill-president...)*

Answer (score 2):

#### Stack Overflow already does this...

1. Joel Coehoorn♦ [won a laptop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40585/free-laptop-to-deserving-meta-user-complete/40589#40589) for only 66 upvotes
2. Many users (with enough reputation to place them on page 1 or 2) [won free stickers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/free-trilogy-stickers-for-top-users/).
3. Also granted to high-rep (actively-helpful) users were some fancy-schmancy [SO-Shirts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38018/whats-going-on-with-stack-overflow-t-shirts).

There are plenty of prizes to be won for having enormous reputation. You just don't learn about them until they're immediately available.

Since you can't go back and get in on that action,
I personally will buy you a laptop for every 1,000 *jpoints* you acquire. *jpoints* are converted forms of standard Stack Overflow reputation. Jon Skeet currently has 12 of them :)

Comment: Let me guess: 1 jpoint = 1 accepted answer to a question asked by you?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the coolest part of Chuck E Cheese for me was being able to get beer .. umm .. `for my parents` ...

When one has a full pitcher with parents thinking he's just `in that big pool of balls, somewhere,` one is increasingly inclined to say `#&$*# the tickets, I have beer!` as he exits through a non-alarmed fire escape.

Just my opinion, however. Oddly, we never went back there after that.

Comment: I don't believe I have ever seen a chuck e cheese that sold beer.

Comment: @earlz, can't speak for the rest of the country but the ones in Maryland did. I have no idea if they still do, but I know that they did.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Chuck E. Cheese then there has to be Rock-afire Explosion!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEZFIsEcyAw

Comment: That was showbiz pizza.

Comment: @Jon, they are the same thing. Chuck E. Cheese used to be just a side character.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Acquire Reputation, disregard wenches]