# Difference between question and 10k close tool

Tags: support, 10k-tools, close-list

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44218/reputation-should-be-the-new-chuck-e-cheese-tickets) has (as of now) 4 close votes, yet the most close votes list in the 10k tools shows that it only has 1.

Why is that?

**10k Tool**

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so_close1.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so_close1.png)

**Question**

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so_close2.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so_close2.png)

Comment: It's like peeking through a keyhole into the secret world of the 10ker!

Comment: dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42299/bug-with-number-of-close-votes-on-summary-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the three oldest close votes are so old that they are not longer in the time interval you selected in the 10k-tools. If you select the "today" intervall it will only show the votes from the last day, etc.

Comment: Yup, this is it. If you select a 7-day window, all four appear; a 1-day window drops it from the list entirely.

Comment: I had 2d selected

Answer (score 1):

What time frame are you looking at for the close votes? Last 2 days? Last 7 days? It's likely that the three extra votes occurred *before* the time frame you are looking at.