# What are the benefits of being a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What advantages do moderators enjoy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45961/what-advantages-do-moderators-enjoy)

What are the benefits of being a moderator, outside of the privileges on the site?

There are certainly benefits to being a contributor on a SE site.

- It might help get you a [job](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/server-fault-hiring-from-the-community-agai/).
- It might get a [unicorn painting](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/).
- It might make you [famous](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/15/stack-overflow-reputation-and-being-a-micro-celebrity.aspx), or at least get you some attention on the internet.

I don't know of any analogous benefits for being an SE mod.

**Is being a moderator really a thankless job, or am I not seeing something?**

Comment: “Benefits”, you say…

Comment: FYI ... i was "only" a 10k rep user not a mod on SF ... didn't become a mod til i started.

Comment: Note that the guy with the unicorn painting is neither a moderator, nor did he need SO to gather a certain amount of fame.

Comment: @balpha I'm saying that was a benefit of him *contributing*, as opposed to being a moderator.

Comment: @CRoss: Ah yes, I misread that.

Answer (score 0):

> It might help get you a job.

This ... best benefit i can think of :-D

Comment: I know, that's contributing on an SE site.  It probably doesn't help to be a moderator.