# Who are the comments moderators?

Tags: support, comments, moderator-tools, moderator-abilities

I have heard that when a user has over 10k reputation the person will become a *moderator* automatically. That is *true* partly, but the user still may not be a comments moderator, who can review flagged comments.

Here are my questions:

- Who are the comments moderators on Stack Exchange sites, like Stack Overflow?
- And how can one become a comments moderator?

Comment: see also: [What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773)

Comment: The dupe doesn't really answer either of the OP's questions.

Comment: I agree with @James. The answer may lie somewhere in the answer to that one, but it's not clear.

Comment: I just realized that I might be asking it at the wrong place, it should belong to [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Can someone migrate it to the correct place please? If you think the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Pangloss the question is fine here on meta.SE since it does have to do with all the sites, not only SO. ie: it works the same on any site

Comment: https://i.imgflip.com/nonu4.jpg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No user becomes a moderator automatically after reaching 10k. They just gain access to [moderation tools](/tools), but that's not the same comparing to the tools *real* moderators (who have a diamond) get.

The comment moderation is the part of the abilities the [moderators on, for example, Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) have, as well as employees of Stack Exchange who have diamonds, notably the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do/99341#99341). Stack Exchange employees have diamonds all across the network; Stack Overflow moderators only have diamonds on Stack Overflow, unless they moderate other sites.

You can become an SO mod by being elected, and you can become a CM by being hired.

Comment: Why would someone wants to be a moderator other than hired? You gain reputations by asking and answering questions, it is also a great way of learning and self-learning process. What are the benefits for the moderators?

Comment: @Pangloss See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45961/what-advantages-do-moderators-enjoy?lq=1).

Comment: I can see a moderator has a black diamond symbol next to the name, is that always true or it can be without the symbol?

Comment: @Pangloss All moderators have that diamond.

Comment: Two things missing: SE developers also have diamond everywhere, and clarify that 10k users get access to moderator *tools*, but not becoming actual moderators. (and the tools do not include editing/deleting comments)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Done.