# Stack Overflow T-shirt, 3rd anniversary edition

Tags: discussion, design, community, t-shirt

I was talking to Jarrod the other night about the early days of Stack Overflow. I then realized SO [came out](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/then-a-miracle-occurs-public-beta/) of private Beta three years ago.

What better way to celebrate this milestone than making a T-shirt for it?

I wanted to come up with a design that's interesting and regular SO users can relate to. The design isn't to promote the Stack Overflow as a web site, because I feel SO has a lot of branding power today than when we made the first round of shirts. This design is about the sub-culture that's formed by SO users.

It's about you.

Without further ado...

[image: SO T-shirt]

[image: SO T-shirt zoom]

Yes, it's a [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) shirt.

Before I go off printing the shirts, I'd like to get some community feedback about the design. If you like it, upvote! If you don't, upvote!

Comment: Love it, hopefully Santa will bring me one :)

Comment: When. When can I buy this. Tomorrow?

Comment: love it, I wonder if all that delicate detail will survive the washing machine

Comment: Spectacular.  You will be giving bobince a couple for free, right??

Comment: @squillman I would expect that a unicorn Piñata full of these be shipped to bobince

Comment: @waffles it will be screen printed so it should be durable. We've had some bad experience with digital printing on black shirts for some of our SE2.0 site shirts before.

Comment: Shouldn't this have a link to the relevant answer? Like `http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732454`? (Just by our CC license.)

Comment: JFC this is amaaaaaazing! I love this answer, I love this shirt. I'd declare my love for you, too, but that might be a bit much. ;)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I can certainly add that.

Comment: Hmmm, my only question is 'Where can I buy one?'

Comment: Genius. I want mine signed by the artist himself. @Jin?

Comment: I want to be able to buy these on the store if I can't get it free, since I'm not a top user on SO as far as rep goes.

Comment: That silhouette looks nothing like [Tony](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx).

Comment: I like the _idea_, but I can make myself a social outcast just fine without the help of a t-shirt, thank you very much.

Comment: I quite liked this version too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18382/help-design-our-stack-overflow-t-shirts/35432#35432

Comment: Joel edited this post and all he did was fix a single typo.  Jeff must be pissed.

Comment: That doesn't look like a narwhal.

Comment: Shut up and take my money.

Comment: Does't this *technically* need a link to Bobince' profile to be a legal redistribution of CC-Wiki'd content? :) Anyway, I like it. Great idea!

Comment: [Been there, done that, didn't get the t-shirt][1]

I hope for better luck this time...


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38018/whats-going-on-with-stack-overflow-t-shirts/43558#43558

Comment: "unholy child weeps the blood of virgins", "summons tainted souls", "ritual infanticide".  I don't think I would want to wear it if the final design contained this sort of text.  Consider that those peering at it will not understand the context of it.  I don't think the "sub-culture" of SO relates to any of those things.

Comment: Where do mods pick theirs up?  No, seriously.

Comment: I'm with @casperOne - I love it (whaddya mean I'm only a sec.se mod?)

Comment: That looks like a weighted freehand circle... Like the ones you can draw using Inkscape's calligraphy tool.

Comment: ***PLEASE LET ME BUY ONE OF THESE.***

Comment: Are these available to buy in any way?

Comment: Is there any way I can buy one? I want one!!!!!!!

Comment: Just spam stackoverflow.com with world class answers. They'll send you one out of sheer desperation sooner or later. Been there, done that.

Comment: How can I get one?

Comment: Shut up and take my money already!

Answer (score 20):

Can we get some of these for some other sites, such as Super User?  Super User just passed its **2nd anniversary**, for example...

Kudos to the clever design of the unicorn! Even though I'm not on SO much, I'd be proud to wear such a shirt with a "hidden meme", because it represents much of the Stack Exchange.

Comment: we're creating a swag package for SU! stay tuned.

Comment: I was about to leave a comment saying that SU ran a big anniversary contest, and then I saw who wrote this answer....

Comment: @PopularDemand :P You won parts of that contest ;)

Comment: ...and Ask Ubuntu celebrates its first anniversary tomorrow.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing is... I always thought the post had a typo and should actually say "the angels are not real" instead of "the angles are not real".

Is that true? Can we hunt down bobince and have him explain which he means? :)

Other than that... love the idea and the design.

Comment: that's correct in Spanish si?

Comment: No idea, honestly. I always assumed it was just English.

Comment: I approve of both angels and unicorn! the more angels the happier I am

Comment: I approve of both angles and angels. If you can't trust math, who can you trust. #TrustNoOne

Comment: "Angles" could refer to HTML's angle brackets (`<` and `>`).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Oh hey, I never thought of that. It kinda makes sense. :)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann yeah, that's what I always thought, too.

Comment: I thought it was referring to interdimensional perspectives.

Answer (score 3):

I just got mine! Thanks everybody at StackExchange!

Comment: Got mine yesterday. Awesome!

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd and Daniel did you guys buy this shirt? Where can I buy one!?

Comment: @gideon nope. only for power users :-) Work on your rep and you'll get the next one...

Comment: ah! :( How much rep are we talking? I have 5k on SO working toward 10k

Comment: @gideon I don't know. At the time I was at about rank 150.