# Yearling badge is not awarded for the first year?

Tags: bug, status-completed, yearling-badge

> **Update:** This appears to be a bug that affects all Stack Overflow
>   users whose accounts are less than two years old. The FAQ is not to
>   blame. Original question follows.

The [list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/164403) says (*emphasis* mine):

> **Yearling**
>
> - silver; awarded multiple times
> - Have `reputation ≥ (number of years as an active user) × 200`
>
>   - *The script that awards this badge only runs on the anniversary
>       of you joining the site*
> - [...]

Alas, that day (October 2nd) has come and gone, still no Yearling badge manifested on my Stack Overflow profile, although I do have the 200 rep required to unlock it.

Does the award script actually run at times other than the one mentioned in the FAQ (like the first day of every month, for instance)? Or is this a bug?

Comment: I got mine on Money shortly after UTC midnight on Aug. 28, around 20 hours after exactly 1 year since I joined.  So I think it runs nightly.  Obviously something else is going on in your case.

Comment: It does run nightly. (More specifically at UTC midnight, which may or may not correspond with your evening)

Comment: Which site is this for?

Comment: Thanks everyone, looks like a bug then. Now I'm curious to know the root cause ;)

Comment: To save people the trouble of clicking through: the OP's rep (42373) is not an issue.

Comment: @ChrisF, that's Stack Overflow, sorry, I should have mentioned that. Question edited accordingly.

Comment: *"Have reputation ≥ (number of years as an active user) × 200"* Jon Skeet has enough reputation to earn himself 1780 yearling badges... And that's not enough to surpass the amount of Nice Answer badges he has.

Comment: Apparently, the script to do the calculation now runs every 30 minutes. And you will be awarded the badge as soon as you qualify rather than only on the anniversary. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209862/203410) and [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209865/203410).

Comment: Correction... every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yep, there's a bug here in a `> (possibly null)` bit of SQL...it'll be fixed and awarded after the next build (including several thousand deserving users who were previously not picked up correctly with the old badge code).

---

*Update:* this just went out, 6,538 yearling badges granted on SO, including the OP, enjoy!

Comment: Then I'm positively astounded nobody reported this bug before. Thank you, Nick :)

Comment: the badge code changed recently, so this is a new bug.

Comment: @Jeff, I was referring to the several thousand deserving users, as I'm not used to being the first reporter under these circumstances ;) Also, the [tee-shirt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108395/164403) looks awesome, many thanks, I can't wait until `6 to 8 weeks` :)

Comment: @Frédéric - oh, that many have earned it in recent history...we have quite a few SO users :)

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the issue is, it's not a gap in the script running schedule. The most recent Yearling was awarded [today](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling) for [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25909/flash)'s third anniversary.

As Tim Stone pointed out in the comments, the bug seems to be that the badge isn't going to people who have been around for just one measly year. In the 27 minutes since I originally posted this answer, 30 new people have received the badge, and 29 of them have been around for either two or three years. (The remaining guy has been around for two and seven months.)

Comment: It looks like it's not awarding the badge to people who have only been here for one year.

Comment: Good catch, @TimStone! Looks like you're exactly right. Also, it looks like my carefully formatted explanation of the reputation requirement math in the list of all badges is wrong... someone with 407 rep got the badge today after two years, seven months.