# How can I order a SO unicorn (3rd anniversary) shirt?

Tags: support, unicorns, t-shirt

[Someone received](http://twitter.com/#!/CrshOverride/status/143797895831883776/photo/1) a  Stack Overflow [3rd anniversary unicorn shirt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition).

[image: SO Unicorn Shirt]

How can I order one, too? I didn't see it in the [shop](http://shop.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok, now I know what I want for christmas!

Comment: Ah, so they are finally shipping. Hope mine gets here before Christmas!

Comment: All we know now is that you get a free t-shirt if your reputation is [86,885](http://stackoverflow.com/users/84651/justin-niessner) or higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this was only offered to "top all-time Stack Overflow users" via a direct email as a thanks for contributions they had made.  I don't think it was sold in the store.

Comment: When rep is no longer appealing, bribe 'em with a unicorn t-shirt eh?

Comment: There are other "special user" bribes. I got my Seasoned Advice swag box this morning. (Not that I'm a very special user on that site, but I squeaked in under wire.) Most of the contents *also* do not appear in the shop. Maybe later you'll be able to buy the apron, but I'm the first kid on my block to get one.

Comment: [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition) is pretty uncool then. "Hey guys, what do you think of this shirt design? It's awesome? Perfect, because you can't have one"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Yeah, I was rather looking forward to this shirt. Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

You had to be cool to get one.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: There is _no way_ those two wavy lines say "Joel Spolsky."