# Stack Overflow T-shirts?

Tags: discussion, t-shirt

I was watching a video on YouTube recently, and it was a talk by Mr. Rory Alsop (a moderator on Stack Exchange site *[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour)*). The guy was wearing a *Information Security* T-shirt. Does Stack Overflow have such T-shirts and if yes where can we buy them?

From the link in the comment:

> We'll continue to make swag, and continue to gift it to people in special circumstances, but you won't be able to purchase it anymore.

Special circumstances?

Comment: There [used to be a store, but it is apparently closed now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store/137580#137580) :-(

Comment: @CodyGray what are the special circumstances

Comment: extreme awesomeness.

Comment: @CodyGray   Any reason you fellows don't want to just license SO and SE designs to something like CafePress?   I could sure use a tshirt & mug!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, special circumstances, such as site anniversaries (not just [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition), but on [several](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/667/it-security-stack-exchange-top-user-swag) [other](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5124/arqade-top-user-swag) [sites](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/programmers-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) as well), and official events set in the physical world.

You cannot purchase official Stack Overflow T-shirts anymore. As implied from your quote, the Stack Exchange store has ceased operations.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is no longer an official store that sells t-shirts. However Stack Exchange occasionally distributes t-shirts for official events.

One example of such special events is the one Super User recently had for the launch of Windows 8. Me and others got [this t-shirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBOmK.jpg) for participating in the event.

Answer (score 2):

I got a t-shirt (I deleted the email, but I think it was sent by Tim Post and I think the gift was from the SE team) after running for the mod election, so I guess anniversaries.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I got it like 3 weeks after, the tag read: "Made in Haitii".  I think they ship it from NY?