# Is this shirt of the "The Answer" on Stack Overflow an official Stack Exchange product?

Tags: discussion, t-shirt, merchandise

I just found [this shirt on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01J0SPEUS) of ["The Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2415822) which looks very similar to a [design found on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261514/2415822) ([and also on here on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108395/242209)). given away in an official capacity.

[image: Shirt]

Is this an official shirt?  It even has a freehand circle!

Comment: Well, the seller is not Stack Exchange. Guess you mean to ask if they got permission from SE to sell the shirt? Not sure about that.

Comment: Wow it doesn't get much more copyright infringement than literally stealing the design off of one of our shirts. They even left all of the black inside the circles and letters that have enclosed space.

Comment: @zaq No they do need permission. Designing text into a unicorn in this fashion is clearly a form of art that becomes copyrighted, regardless of the content that was actually used to create it. If they had just copy-pasted the answer in plain-text onto a shirt with attribution, then sure. But they didn't do that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess we can infer that the seller is not SE, but that doesn't really answer the question.  A user who won swag could sell it on ebay.  Then the seller wouldn't be SE itself, but the product would still be official.  My question still stands: is this an official Stack Exchange product?  But I guess we all know the answer based on animuson's comments...

Comment: @JAL A user that won it and was reselling wouldn't have it in all those colors and sizes.

Comment: @Erik I know, I'm just giving an alternate example.

Comment: Best part: List price: $50.00 Actual price $13.10

Comment: @animuson There's also a ladies cut: https://smile.amazon.com/Eagle-womens-Fashion-Overflow-neonGreen/dp/B01J7CI9XQ/

Comment: @animuson so time to hire a good lawyer and sew them.... no? SE can make good money out of it and use it for good cause. ;)

Comment: I'm gonna pass this along internally to see what we can do here, if anything.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks! Do I get a copy of the real shirt for reporting a knockoff?  Pretty please?  :)

Comment: @JAL I don't think we have any left, unfortunately... but I bet I can at least hook you up with the current version of our t-shirts. Drop me an email with your size and shipping address (my email's in my profile). :)

Comment: @AdamLearn Email sent, thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this an official shirt?

No, as SE employee animuson confirmed [in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287853/is-this-shirt-of-the-the-answer-on-stack-overflow-an-official-stack-exchange-p#comment934229_287853) [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287853/is-this-shirt-of-the-the-answer-on-stack-overflow-an-official-stack-exchange-p#comment934230_287853), this is not official merchandise of Stack Exchange, and was illegally copied from something SE offered in the past.

Answer (score 7):

Well, we know that the shirt on Amazon was not genuine, but the Stack Exchange community team was nice enough to send me an actual genuine one with the Stack Overflow logo.  Thank you!

[image: Unicorn shirt]

Note that the genuine shirt has the Stack Overflow logo and the URL of the "the answer."

Comment: Is that a FHRC in there?! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the bounty!  The Stack Exchange team are the real MVPs here, hope they can get the shirt taken down.

Comment: "get the shirt taken down" - and leave them half naked? :P

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, the bootleg sellers deserve it!